# Disabling AEM Assets

Tags: adobe, aem

According to Adobe

> **Is AEM Assets available as a separate Package?**
>   No. To ease installation and deployment, all AEM Applications and add-ons are delivered in one single package with all functionality included. This does not imply that you have permission to use all features in the package.
>
> **How can I prevent my users from using AEM Assets if I did not license AEM Assets?**
>   You can remove all AEM Assets-specific workflows, components, taxonomies, options and the AEM Assets admin from AEM. Doing so prevents your users from accidentally using AEM Assets features that you did not license.

https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-4/assets/using/medialibrary.html

Are there any packages available for this? If not, is there straightforward outline of this procedure?

Comment: Are you using AEM Sites? If so, the DAM is available, and that won't be a license violation. You can reach them to clarify

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your issue clear, you want to restrict your users to access certain AEM features. 
The following are the ways to restrict the dam asset feature in AEM.

I am not sure whether AEM provides any by default feature to enable or disable AEM assets feature because AEM assets are also part of it's content tree or node tree which is included in AEM's standard licensing.

1. You can restrict the "/content/dam" access at useradmin section at  http://localhost:4502/useradmin
2. You can use the "deny" rule in your dispatcher configurations if you are using dispatcher in your project.
3. You can have a 404 redirect for content/dam node in your publisher server.
4. You can use restricted access which comes under AEM authentication as AEM login feature for "content/dam" node.
5. You can write a custom AEM configuration to enable and disable /content/dam feature access.

Do let me know if you are not happy with my answers or if I am not able to understand the question by commenting on this.